# Gradle module not found in custom uml task

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, javadoc

I am using this "plugin" on javadoc to generate a UML Class Diagram with Gradle: https://github.com/talsma-ict/umldoclet
This "plugin" uses javadoc to create UML Class Diagrams.

I am working with the JavaFX library to build my application. When I run my custom task that should generate the image I get an error in my `module-info.java` that `javafx.controls` cannot be found.

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
id 'application'
id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    umlDoclet
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.18'
    // Used for generating UML class diagram
    umlDoclet "nl.talsmasoftware:umldoclet:2.0.6"
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    options.docletpath = configurations.umlDoclet.files.asType(List)
    options.doclet = "nl.talsmasoftware.umldoclet.UMLDoclet"
}

task generateUmlClass(type: Javadoc) {
    dependsOn("javadoc")
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    destinationDir = reporting.file("uml")
    options.docletpath = configurations.umlDoclet.files.asType(List)
    options.doclet = "nl.talsmasoftware.umldoclet.UMLDoclet"
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/nl.avans.sagrada.MainApp"

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'Sagrada'
    }
}
```

I tried adding `dependsOn("javadoc")` so I would build first but this doesn't seem to work.

My `module-info.java`

```
module Sagrada {
requires javafx.controls;
requires java.sql;

opens nl.avans.sagrada to javafx.base;
opens nl.avans.sagrada.controllers to javafx.controls;
opens nl.avans.sagrada.view.scenes to javafx.controls;
opens nl.avans.sagrada.view.panes to javafx.controls;

opens nl.avans.sagrada.database to java.sql;

exports nl.avans.sagrada;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.controllers;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.view.scenes;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.view.panes;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.interfaces;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.helpers;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.models;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.database;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.database.annotations;
exports nl.avans.sagrada.database.models;
}
```

Whenever I try to run `gradle generateUmlClass` it gives following error:

```
2:55:13 PM: Executing task 'generateUmlClass'...

> Configure project :
Found module name 'Sagrada'

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar
> Task :startScripts
> Task :distTar
> Task :distZip
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build

> Task :generateUmlClass FAILED
D:\Avans\Blok 2\Sagrada-Core\src\main\java\module-info.java:2: error: module not found: javafx.controls
    requires javafx.controls;
                   ^
D:\Avans\Blok 2\Sagrada-Core\src\main\java\module-info.java:3: error: module not found: javafx.fxml
    requires javafx.fxml;
                   ^
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateUmlClass'.
> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'D:\Avans\Blok 2\Sagrada-Core\build\tmp\generateUmlClass\javadoc.options'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
7 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 2 up-to-date
2:55:15 PM: Task execution finished 'generateUmlClass'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you are adding two javadoc tasks:

```
javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    options.docletpath = configurations.umlDoclet.files.asType(List)
    options.doclet = "nl.talsmasoftware.umldoclet.UMLDoclet"
}

task generateUmlClass(type: Javadoc) {
    dependsOn("javadoc")
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    destinationDir = reporting.file("uml")
    options.docletpath = configurations.umlDoclet.files.asType(List)
    options.doclet = "nl.talsmasoftware.umldoclet.UMLDoclet"
}
```

With same options in both and when you run `./gradlew generateUmlClass` you are calling both tasks.

If you add some required options to one of them, the other will miss it. So you should only use one. Let's keep the default task `javadoc`.

Now:

```
javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    options.docletpath = configurations.umlDoclet.files.asType(List)
    options.doclet = "nl.talsmasoftware.umldoclet.UMLDoclet"
    destinationDir = reporting.file("uml")
}
```

If you run `./gradlew javadoc`, you get the errors you have reported:

```
...src/main/java/module-info.java:2: error: module not found: javafx.controls
    requires javafx.controls;
                   ^
```

This happens because JavaFX is modular, and you should put it in the module-path.

The JavaFX gradle `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin does precisely that for the `run` task, but not for the Javadoc one, so to fix the issue we need to add an option to the task with the module-path.

Using gradle's [`addStringOption`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html), the way to do it is:

```
javadoc {
    options.addStringOption('-module-path', ...)
    ...
}
```

The module path now can be taken from the classpath (`classpath.asPath`), however the JavaFX plugin uses `implementation` instead of the deprecated `compile`, so the now we need to use `runtimeClasspath`:

```
javadoc {
    options.addStringOption('-module-path', configurations.runtimeClasspath.asPath)
    ...
}
```

Finally, this is all you should need:

```
javadoc {
    options.addStringOption('-module-path', configurations.runtimeClasspath.asPath)
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    options.docletpath = configurations.umlDoclet.files.asType(List)
    options.doclet = "nl.talsmasoftware.umldoclet.UMLDoclet"
    destinationDir = reporting.file("uml")
}
```

Now running `./gradlew javadoc` should work successfully.

At least I can get some nice SVG images under `build/reports/uml:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand it now a little bit better. One thing I am getting my SVG like this: http://prntscr.com/q56os7. Could you explain how I would get the diagram like the above example? With the methods and attributes?

Comment: I don’t know the UML library, I just added it to a regular HelloFX sample, and ran the JavaDoc task...

Answer (score 1):

Please let me provide some background to this question which seems resolved already.
I am the author of [UMLDoclet](https://github.com/talsma-ict/umldoclet); it is a Javadoc [Doclet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/javadoc/doclet/package-summary.html), which is indeed kind of a *plugin* to the Javadoc tool.

It works as follows:

1. Call the `Standard` Doclet from your Javadoc version to generate the regular HTML documentation.
2. Generate the following [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com) diagrams:

   1. Class diagram for each documented class
   2. Package diagram for each documented package
   3. Package dependency diagram with a dependency graph containing all documented packages (This was the diagram you shared, it contains many [dependency cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) by the way)
3. Postprocess the generated HTML documents to embed the class, package and dependency diagrams where possible.

Because the doclet uses [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com), you have to have [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org) installed locally when generating the diagrams.

By the way; I would have appreciated it a lot if you had included a link to this Stackoverflow post in the [issue you filed](https://github.com/talsma-ict/umldoclet/issues/215) in my github repo.

I'm glad your issue was resolved and I'd like to thank [José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda) for his elaborate answer!